# PM2 Logrotate - install error

Tags: node.js, pm2, pm2-logrotate

I am trying to install pm2 logrotate on ubuntu server. I run the command

`pm2 install pm2-logrotate`

I get the following error

`[PM2][Module][ERROR] Unknown module`

Any ideas on what could be wrong?

Comment: Using sudo before the command fixed the problem.